# Error al 'contar' en consulta SQL

Tags: php

Hice una consulta para contar los miembros que están unidos en cada grupo de un usuario, pero en todos los grupos me cuenta la misma cantidad de miembros unidos. ¿Alguien me ayuda?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El número **5** es la cantidad de usuarios unidos al grupo, en el primer grupo debería haber **5** y en el segundo sólo **1**

Tabla group_memberships

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla groups
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$list_q = Db::query('SELECT m.group_id, p.id 
                     FROM group_memberships m 
                     LEFT JOIN groups p ON p.id = m.group_id 
                     WHERE m.group_id = p.id');
```

Comment: No, un amigo me recomendó hacer así para ahorrarme líneas de código. Es la primera vez que lo intento y maso menos salió pero tengo ese error que dije arriba.

Comment: Deberías agregar la estructura de las tablas involucradas en tu consulta para que de ese modo comprendamos mejor lo que tratas de obtener

Comment: Ya las coloqué, actualice la página.

Comment: Estás usando Laravel? Publicá los modelos para ver sus nombres y relaciones. Si querés escribir la consulta a mano, tenés que sumar un `COUNT(player_id) AS cantidad` (o como quieras llamarlo) al select y un `GROUP BY group_id` al final.

Comment: Me podrías mostrar la consulta modificada, sé poco de consultas SQL.

Comment: Podrías contestar mi pregunta?

Comment: No estoy usando Laravel, simplemente me dieron ese tipo de consultas para "ahorrarme líneas de código", pero pensando que funcionaría lo probé pero no dio resultado. ¿Cómo lo debería hacer?